# Text wrapping around icon with spans inside of h3 tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my text to align so that the text does not wrap around this icon.  I am having trouble because my icon and my text are inside of an h3 tag and an anchor and I am using spans.  The typical ways for that I would usually make this work will not work because I am using spans and because both the icons and the text are inside of h3 and anchors.

What I am looking for is

```
icon Test test test test test test
     Test test test test test test
```

What I am getting is

```
icon Test test test test test test
Test test Test test test test test
```

```css
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
  min-height: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.fa-plus::before {
  content: "\f067";
}

.textalignleft {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="fc-panel-title ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-17" aria-controls="ui-id-18" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span class="fa fa-plus fc-iconspace"></span>
  
  <span class="textalignleft">Does American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?</span></a></h3>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upKGe/650/)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the display of the anchor and span to table-cell:

```css
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
  min-height: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.fa-plus::before {
  content: "\f067";
}

a,
.textalignleft {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="fc-panel-title ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-17" aria-controls="ui-id-18" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span class="fa fa-plus fc-iconspace"></span>
  </a>
  <span class="textalignleft">Does American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?</span></h3>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt wrap the second span in the anchor. The whole thing is wrapped by the h3 and the anchor.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to apply `display: flex;` to  `h3 > a` and erase the `text-align: right` from `.textalignleft`. That will create two blocks of equal height inside the `a` inside the `h3`:

Edited snippet after comment and changed question:

```css
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
  min-height: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.fa-plus::before {
  content: "\f067";
}

.textalignleft {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
h3 > a {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="fc-panel-title ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-17" aria-controls="ui-id-18" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span class="fa fa-plus fc-iconspace"></span>
  
  <span class="textalignleft">Does American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?American AgCredit offer special programs for young, beginning, or small farmers/ranchers?</span></a></h3>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt wrap the second span in the anchor.  The whole thing is wrapped by the h3 and the anchor.

Comment: Nevertheless, almost the same solution, only that you apply flex to the `a` tag insde the`h3` - see my edited answer and snippet above.